# show login page while logged out(clicking back button)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have react based app in which I stuck little bit in logout module.When I logout it comes to login page but after clicking back button it comes to previous page.Can I do something like

```
<Route path="/only-for-logged-in-users-page" component={SomeComponent} onEnter={redirectToLoginIfNotLoggedIn} />
```

What to write in onEnter?

Comment: That depends entirely on how you've implemented authentication. Can you provide more relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a good example of how to redirect if not authenticated:

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js#L135

Answer (score 0):

The Route component from react router supports an 
[OnEnter function](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback).

With this you are able to replace the route you are about the navigate to with something else. I'd check for my authentication status in here, and if required, replace it with the login URL.

You could also consider creating a Higher Order Component that wraps the Route component and handles the authentication logic before rendering the normal Route. This would let you do something like:

```
<AuthenticatedRoute path"/only-for-loggedin" etc />
```